# What is the equivalent degree of a Diploma in Information Technology from India?

Tags: computer-science, united-states, degree, bachelor, india

After my 10th grade I joined a polytechnic college for a specialization in Infomation Technology (Diploma in Information Technology). Now, I am in my final year of under-graduate studies (Bachelor of Technology in Information Technology), and I want to pursue my graduate studies from the United States of America.

One of the universities that I am applying to did not offer the option of “Diploma in Information Technology” in their online application form. After doing some [research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diploma#Usage) I found out that:

> In [India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India), a diploma is a specific academic award usually earned in professional/vocational courses, e.g., Engineering, Pharmacy, Design, etc. In such cases, a diploma is specific in rank than a [Bachelor's degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor%27s_degree) of that discipline but equivalent to general degree in that discipline, e.g., [Diploma in Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diploma_in_Engineering) of [Electronics Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronics_Engineering) is rated differently than [Bachelor of Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_of_Technology) in [Electronics Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronics_Engineering) but is equivalent to [Bachelor of Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_of_Science) in [Electronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronics).

If so, then what is the equivalent degree of a Diploma in Information Technology in India? Is it Bachelor of Science in Information Technology?

Comment: I think the major problem would be the amount of credit hours in that program. Almost all US undergraduate degrees are 4 years long and this varies widely around the world. In the US, a diploma is somewhat equivalent to a high school degree - perhaps slightly more. You could apply to college, but getting in to grad school might be difficult. There are other options such as completing one or two years of college and then applying for grad school, but it depends on the program you are doing.

Answer (score 4):

It's not "equivalent" to any US degree.The US educational system is sufficiently different that no such equivalent degree exists in the US.

If an online application doesn't have your specific credentials as an option, choose "Other" and specify. Don't invent equivalencies.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that the diploma would be similar to a degree that you would get out of a US vocational college, or perhaps a community college. Those are associate degrees, which are below a bachelors degree - it's a two year degree that could be transferred for credits if you were pursuing a bachelors degree.

I would suggest that you look for an Academic equivalency service that will provide you with a solution to your issue. Of course, you cannot invent equivalencies for your degree. Another option would be to call the international students affairs office at the university you hope to apply to. They may have some suggestions on what to put on the application and what your degree is equivalent to. They may even tell you to use an academic equivalency service.

Comment: It's similar, but not similar enough that the OP can write on his application that he has an associate's degree...

Comment: I didn't say that the degree is the same as an associates and that it should be put on an application. Of course, the applicant should contact the university on such matters. That's what I would recommend even before posting on this forum.